# Stable-baselines3 vs. Tianshou

Tags: reinforcement-learning, stable-baselines, tianshou

What would you recommend between [Stable-Baselines3](https://github.com/DLR-RM/stable-baselines3) and [Tianshou](https://github.com/thu-ml/tianshou) for applied research in Reinforcement Learning?
Can anyone provide a comparison of the strengths and weaknesses of each library?